# Problema con Scanner.next() al leer Input desde el teclado

Tags: java

Tengo una clase Persona:

```
public class Persona {

    String Nombre;
    int Edad;
    String Intereses;
    String Descripcion;

    public Persona(String Nombre,int Edad,String Intereses,String Descripcion)
    {        
            this.Nombre = Nombre;
            this.Edad = Edad;
            this.Intereses = Intereses;
            this.Descripcion = Descripcion;

    }

    public String getNombre(){
        return Nombre;
    }

    public int getEdad(){
        return Edad;
    }
    public String geIntereses(){
        return Intereses;
    }

    public String getDescripcion(){
        return Descripcion;
    }
}
```

Y otra clase con un método para crear un objeto de tipo `Persona` con `Input` desde el teclado:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class clase {

         static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void creaPersona(){

        System.out.print("Nombre:");
        String Nombre = sc.next();
        System.out.print("Edad:");
        int Edad = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Intereses:");
        String Intereses = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Descripcion:");
        String Descripcion = sc.next();

        Persona persona = new Persona(Nombre,Edad,Intereses,Descripcion);

        System.out.print("Persona creada!");
    }

   public static void main(String[]args){

       creaPersona();

   }

}
```

El problema es cuando me pide en la consola el `Input` de `Intereses`,
y pues si escribo con "espacios" el programa se salta el `Input` de `Descripcion` y termina prematuramente sin poder insertar el input para `Descripcion`.

```
Nombre:bryan
Edad:20
Intereses:
carros chocones , muscia , videojeuegos
Descripcion:
Persona creada!BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 20 seconds)
```

Mi idea con el `Input` `Intereses` es escribir algo largo y talvez en modo de lista:

-Musica
-Juegos
-etc

y con el de `Descripcion` escribir simplemente unas 3 lineas de text normal.

Comment: Tienes que parsear el int Edad¡ , puesto que estás utilizando el scanner para los strings y para el int. Creo que es ahí donde se encuentra el fallo.